# Automapper naming convention with underscore/PascalCase properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 2 classes I want to map with Automapper:

```
namespace AutoMapperApp
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string Test { get; set; }
        public string property_name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace AutoMapperApp
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public string Test { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Automapper config:

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace AutoMapperApp
{
    public static class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration;

        public static void RegisterMappings()
        {
            MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>();
                cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
                cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

According the Wiki of Automapper this should work:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration

But my unittest fails:

```
using Xunit;
using AutoMapperApp;

namespace AutoMapperTest
{
    public class Test
    {
        [Fact]
        public void AssertConfigurationIsValid()
        {
            AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
            AutoMapperConfig.MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
=============================================
Class1 -> Class2 (Destination member list)
AutoMapperApp.Class1 -> AutoMapperApp.Class2 (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
PropertyName
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With help from the AutoMapper project in GitHub:

> Try the CreateMap after you set the convention.

```
public static void RegisterMappings()
{
    MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
        cfg.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
  public static void RegisterMappings()
  {
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
      cfg.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>();
      cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
      cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
    });
  }
}
```

I'm assuming you are calling this in your app_start method. AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();

For organizational purposes you can separate your mappings into profiles, register them and set your conventions on a profile-by-profile basis if you don't need the convention to be global like in your example.

To answer your question, it looks like you created a mapper configuration but did not initialize it so Automapper doesn't know what mapping you're talking about.

Comment: Mapper.Initialize is not encouraged since version 4.2: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/ Properties with exactly the same name are mapped without problems.